# Can i make restricions already from table creation?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Assume i have 3 tables

```
courses(id)
students(id)
student_courses(Primary Key is (courses.id,students.id)
```

I have to input a lot of data and i want **one student take at most 10 courses**, can i do something in creation table `student_courses` to stop adding another courses when student will reach proper number of courses?

Comment: I'd consider triggers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CHECK` constraint to find out the count of one student.

follow below steps

i.e. create the table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student_courses
( Course_id int , 
  student_id  int , 
    .
    .
    .
    PRIMARY KEY (Course_id,student_id) 
);
```

Create function to return the count of `student_id`

```
Create FUNCTION studentCount(studentId int)
Returns int
AS
BEGIN
Declare Count int

   Select Count=Count(*) from student_courses Where student_id=studentId

Return Count
END
/
```

now add `CHECK` constraints to the table

```
Alter Table student_courses add Constraint CK_student_course Check(studentCount(student_id)<=10)
```

and everytime when you inserts data for student id and course id in table it will check whether 10 or below records available for that student and it will restrict to insert 11th record in the table.